# Nhibernate sends delete query twice

Tags: c#, nhibernate

When performing NHibernate delete on some entity, we have the following error:

```
StaleStateException - Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1
```

We have already deleted tons of such entities in our app, but this time, it can't. Using SQL Server Profiler, I can see that NHibernate sends the needed queries to delete relationship and so, then sends twice the `delete from XXX where id = xx`. And it crashes after the second query (it should returns 0 as the first delete query actually deleted the entity).

With other entities of same kind, there is only one `delete`... I'm looking for tips to investigate more on the issue.

**EDIT:** the deleted entity is aggregate root.

Comment: Where is your code? Query, domain classes, configuration?

Comment: I know that I didn't provide any code: I can't. All I can say is that the same delete query is sent twice, with nothing between.

Comment: Is some cascading involved ? You should give a look at all other pending session operations on the same object or related objects

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail in the question, I think the best we can do are random guesses at what the problem could be.  I have one guess as to what the problem is, and perhaps other people have other guesses, so I'll start this post as a community wiki so that other people can contribute possible causes for this problem.

#### 1. Multiple identical removals from a `cascade="all-delete-orphan"` bag.

If a bag already contained an item, but you added that same item again, perhaps it is possible to get two deletes on the same item when you remove those two identical items from the collection.

Any other ideas?